# Как проверять отключение COM-Порта?

Tags: c#, com, serial, port

Имеется класс подключения к COM-Порту. В нем я запускаю проверку списка портов каждые 5 секунд и проверяю - существует ли мое устройство в списке. Заметил, что если отключить устройство и был выполнен SeialPort.Open(), то устройство не пропадает из списка (тоже самое в диспетчере устройств).

Каким способом можно проверять разрыв соединения с устройством?

Подключение к порту:

```
 public void Connect()
 {
    serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudrate, parity);
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Read);
 }
```

Получение данных:

```
 private void Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         barcode = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadTo("\r");
         barcode = barcode.Replace(" ", "");
         barcode = barcode.Replace("\n", "");
         barcode = barcode.Replace("\r", "");

         UpdateData?.Invoke();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Error(ex, "Ошибка программы: Port.Read");
         Disconnect();
     }
 }
```

Отключение:

```
 public void Disconnect()
 {
    if (serialPort != null)
    {
       serialPort.Close();
       serialPort.Dispose();
       serialPort.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Read);
    }
 }
```

Проверка существующих портов:

```
 while (serialPort != null && serialPort.IsOpen)
 {
     // Проверяем наличие порта каждые 5сек
     if (!SerialPort.GetPortNames().Contains(serialPort.PortName))
     {
         Logger.Error("Устройство не обнаружено", "[Ошибка] [COMPORT]: " + serialPort.PortName + " не найден!");
         Disconnect();
     }

     Thread.Sleep(5000);
 }
```

Comment: COM порт на компьютере настоящий или виртуальный, через USB? Не виртуальный COM порт существует всегда, неважно, подключено к нему что-нибудь или нет. Виртуальный порт должен дать ошибку при отключении устройства.

Comment: @AlexF Подключен ручной сканер штрихкодов по USB с эмуляцией RS-232. В диспетчере устройство отображается в Портах (COM).

Comment: Значит, если порт не открыт в программе, и устройство отключено, то оно пропадает из списка. А если порт открыт в программе, и устройство отключено, то оно не пропадает?

Comment: @AlexF Все верно.

Comment: Надо найти какую-то операцию, которая в таком случае не проходит. Например, что дает BytesToRead? Есть ли event ErrorReceived? Есть ли в документации на устройство какой-то способ проверки функционирования, например, послать какой-то пакет и получить на него ответ?

Comment: @AlexF BytesToRead в цикле проверки будет 0 выдавать (т.к. ничего не считывается в этот момент). ErrorReceived ничего не сообщает. Заметил, если подключить устройство и открыть порт, а потом отключить и обратно включить, то порт без переподключения отлично отправляет данные и программа все данные получает. Попробую почитать документацию, спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Значит, виртуальный порт хорошо сделан, ведет себя как настоящий. Надо искать решение на уровне протокола коммуникации с устройством. Может, при отключении есть что-то в System Log, тогда на Win32 + C++ можно перехватить какой-нибудь USB event.  Но это очень непросто.

Answer (score 0):

При подключении или отключении USB устройства вызывается вот это:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
    if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        WindowsMessageHandler?.Invoke(m);
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Соответственно, сюда можно подключить обработчик

```
public event Action<Message> WindowsMessageHandler;
```